# JavaScript test() RegExp method in JavaScript: lastIndex property not advancing

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I am experiencing an unexpected behavior when using the test() RegExp method in JavaScript.
Even when using the g global flag, does lastIndex property not advance when using a literal regex and string with the test() method?
Please see the attached image, which contains relevant details. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  :)  Thank you!

[image: [JavaScript test() RegExp method issue]]

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Your `alt` is a *boolean*, that you're just logging over and over again - referencing it doesn't change anything, it doesn't run any code other than checking what the variable contains (which ends up being the boolean `true`)

Comment: Thank you for kindly replying, CertainPerformance.  :)   I greatly appreciate your guidance.  My apologies for the image instead of code as text.  I will make sure to always include code as text in future questions/posts.  :)